# How can I see the vb code of an UI made Publisher template

Tags: vba, automation, userform, ms-publisher

I'm using a publisher document as a template to create fitting instructions for our products. Everytime we launch a new product an individual instruction is produced which involves a lot of copy and pasting and then translating the master document into 4 different languages.

Although being individual to the product, there are only 5 sets of instructions with their own wordings (which doesn't change) and pics, the layout of the document is the same across all 5.

I was thinking to create a user form to enter the product name, choose the required set, insert photos and save the new doc as .pub and .pdf (only in English, I want to get this running first)

I tried around with Access and mail merge but it doesn't work the way I need it to. So I reverted to using VB in publisher where I've been basically able to return the text boxes, however, I can't see a way to display the code of the entire document with all text boxes and their formatting. Is this possible or would I have to code the entire document from scratch?

Thanks for reading and your input.